# Submit returning a blank page

Tags: php, mysql

A blank page is returned when I try to add a new note. My code is in php and the DB is mysql

This is the php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  $candidate_id = $_POST['candidate_id'];
  $Notes = $_POST['notes'];
  if ($Notes != "") {
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO notes (notes_id, candidate_id, notes) VALUES(DEFAULT,'$candidate_id','$Notes')";
    $result3=mysql_query($sql3);
    if (!$result3) {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "</br>1 note added"
  }
}
mysql_close();
```

The code for the form

```
<div id="tab3">
  <h2> Notes </h2>
  <dl>
    <dt>Notes</dt>
    <dd>
      <textarea id="notes" style="width: 80%; height: 150px;" name="notes"></textarea>
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <?php
    echo "<a href =newCandidate.php?id=$contact_id><input style =\"right:2em; bottom:1em;\" type =\"button\" name =\"update\" value =\"Submit\"></a>";
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: first, avoid mysql_* functions

Comment: second, don't trust $_POST

Comment: Is the note added in your db ?

Comment: @ImaneFateh no the note is not added

Comment: `if (srtlen($Notes) > 1)`

Comment: Turn on error reporting to see what is wrong

Comment: What is the field `notes_id`? Do you need to assign `DEFAULT` to it? If it's an auto_increment field, you can just omit from an INSERT completely.

Comment: @ConnorTumbleson if not $_POST what should I trust?

Comment: please post your code for form here. Something might have gone wrong with the input names

Comment: @user2510479 - you should sanitise the input you get from $_POST. For instance, if the notes includes an apostrophe, your SQL statement will break. Ideally, you should use a prepared statement and bound variables.

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet I have now included the code for the form

Comment: are you sure you've wrapped your input cells in **<form></form>** ?

Comment: yes I have @MuhammedHedayet

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
```

instead of

```
 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
```

the name of the submit button is **update** not **Submit** on your form

also stop using mysql_* functions. If you have to use them for now, at least escape the inputs properly before inserting them to database.

Comment: Thanks. Another reason my code was not working was that the input type was button but it should have been submit for a form. Appreciate you looking through my code and giving your input. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To sum this up:

use error reporting in the beginning of your script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Echo out the SQL query (after you created it) to see what weird, unescaped stuff you want to send to the server:

```
echo $sql3;
exit; // to prevent execution
```

Try the echoed SQL with phpmyadmin to see if the problem is your query or the missing database connection.

There are a lot more bad things in your script, but for first error-tracing those tips might be okay... **In general, i recommend you to completely rewrite this after you read into SQL injection, modern database query methods, proper php coding etc. ! To finish your project, you should consider using a micro framework to get quick and secure results.**

Answer (score 0):

in your submit button you have no form

try this

```
      <div id ="tab3">
  <h2> Notes </h2>
 <dl><dt>Notes</dt><dd><form action="" method="post" name="myform"><textarea id="notes" style="width: 80%; height: 150px;" name="notes"></textarea></dd></dl>
      <?php   echo "<a href =newCandidate.php?id=$contact_id><input style =\"right:2em; bottom:1em;\" type =\"button\" name =\"update\" value =\"Submit\"></a></form>";
    ?>   </div>
```

- and please avoid using inner css , please use classes in other css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){                

    // Code 

<?php
 }
else
{ 
echo "form not submited properly";
}
?> 

<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'nav.php';
include 'config.php';
?>
```

Except

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'nav.php';
include 'config.php';
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){                

    // Code 

<?php
 }
else
{ 
echo "form not submited properly";
}
?>
```